# Best way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned long?

Tags: java, unsigned

For certain hash functions in Java it would be nice to see the value as an unsigned integer (e.g. for comparison to other implementations) but Java supports only signed types.  We can convert a signed `int` to an "unsigned" `long` as such:

```java
public static final int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;
public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
  ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / BITS_PER_BYTE);
  buf.putInt(Integer.SIZE / BITS_PER_BYTE, x);
  return buf.getLong(0);
}
getUnsignedInt(-1); // => 4294967295
```

However, this solution seems like overkill for what we're really doing.  Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int x = -1;
long y = x & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
```

Or am I missing something?

```
public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
    return x & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
}
```

Comment: @Paranaix I believe that would also work. It's been a while since I wrote this answer, so I think the reason why I padded with zeros was out of habit, since I do mostly C++ and the integer promotion rules there are more complicated with signed/unsigned types.

Answer (score 63):

The standard way in Java 8 is [`Integer.toUnsignedLong(someInt)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedLong-int-), which is equivalent to [@Mysticial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578666/1174467).

Answer (score 18):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides [`UnsignedInts.toLong(int)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#toLong-int-)...as well as a variety of other utilities on unsigned integers.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a function like

```
public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
    return x & (-1L >>> 32);
}
```

however in most cases you don't need to do this.  You can use workarounds instead. e.g.

```
public static boolean unsignedEquals(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

For more examples of workarounds for using unsigned values. [Unsigned utility class](http://code.google.com/p/java-unsigned/source/browse/trunk/unsigned/src/main/java/com/google/code/unsigned/Unsigned.java)

Comment: Your getUnsignedInt function doesn't work. I made a serious error in my program as I didn't test it. :((

Comment: getUnsignedInt appears to work as-is. `>>>` is correct. `>>` causes sign extension, and -1L right-shifted with sign extension any amount always results in a value with all ones.

Comment: getUnsignedInt works for me too, as-is.

Answer (score 2):

other solution.

```
public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
    if(x > 0) return x;
    long res = (long)(Math.pow(2, 32)) + x;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Math.pow is very expensive and calculated every time. By comparison `1l << 32` is fast and only calculated by the compiler. (And doesn't need to be cast to a long.

Comment: Can you please give me some link or description on how these conversion work, m not able to understand it.

Comment: Because int is 32 bit and use two's complement to represent. You can check two's complement in wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to get more details

Answer (score -2):

Just my 2 cents here, but I think it's a good practice to use:

`public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) { 
    return x & (~0L); // ~ has precedence over & so no real need for brackets
}`

instead of:

> return x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;

In this situation there's not your concern how many 'F's the mask has. It shall always work!

Comment: This is completely wrong. The int is promoted to a long, and then you're masking it with a bit string of 64 ones which does nothing. The following prints -1 instead of 4294967295:

    int i = -1;
    long j = i & (~0L);
    System.out.println(j);

Comment: yes it's my bad, I confused 0xFFFFFFFFL with ~0L which obvious it's not the case

Answer (score -4):

```
long abs(int num){
    return num < 0 ? num * -1 : num;
}
```

Comment: please read about two's complement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which describes how signed numbers are usually represented. You cant just take absolute value for resolving that issue (http://tadej.me/twos-complement-and-absolute-values/).