# Compare a 4 byte usigned integer (from file) with a defined integer value in java

Tags: java

I have a file that contains data to read in little-endian binary format. To parse the file, I first read a 4-byte unsigned integer, then depending on the value of that integer, I execute different read routines.

Using ByteBuffer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578639/best-way-to-convert-a-signed-integer-to-an-unsigned-long), I can read a 4 byte unsigned int as a long. But in my code, I would like to use a switch statement, and java does not allow switches on longs.

Since I'm just checking for equality, it would be fine to read the 4 bytes as a signed integer and compare it to my known value. However, my reference values are all defined as unsigned ints (e.g. 0xc15ab354). Is there a good way to convert these to signed ints (yes, it could be done manually, but this introduces the possibility of error) for comparison, or a better way to do the comparison?

Comment: Why is it so important you use a switch statement?  Just use an `if` statement instead.  Sounds like it'd prevent an unnecessary headache.

Comment: @William - I think it's cleaner and easier to read & extend to have a switch than a line of cascading if-else statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite simple. If you just use `0xc15ab354` as an `int` literal, you'll get the signed integer with that exact binary representation, so you can use it directly in your `switch` statement, just as it is.