# How to convert an integer type to an unsigned type?I'm coding in Java

Tags: java

for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String str = "11111111111111111111111111111111";
    int a = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(str, 2);
    System.out.println(a);
}`
```

result:-1
but doesn't the range of unsigned int type is 0~2^32 - 1?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578639/best-way-to-convert-a-signed-integer-to-an-unsigned-long)! It's an old question from stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578639/best-way-to-convert-a-signed-integer-to-an-unsigned-long

Comment: Signedness is only in your mind. It's just bits after bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, pass in your int to this function

```
  public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
        return x & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
    }
```