# Bit masking unsigned and signed values

Tags: java

In the example [provided here](https://engineering.pinterest.com/blog/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet),

> We created a 64 bit ID that contains the  shard ID = 16 bit,  the type
>   of the containing data = 10 bit, and where this data is in the table
>   (local ID) = 36.
>
> The savvy additionology experts out there will notice that only adds
>   to 62 bits. My past in compiler and chip design has taught me that
>   reserve bits are worth their weight in gold. So we have two (set to
>   zero).

So does this mean:

**Question One:**

They can have 2^16, range of 0-65536 shards ?

Type ID of 2^10, range of 0-1024 types ?

Local ID of 2^36, range of 0-68719476736 local id's ?

Also I am trying to replicate their hashing function in Java

| represents separation of two sets of 32 bits to make it easier to visualize.

# represents a bit shift of 46, enclosing 18 bit of which 2 are reserved - ShardId

~ represents a bit shift of 36, enclosing 10 bit - Type Id
The remaining 36 bits - local ID:

#0000 0000 0000 0000 00#~00 0000 0000~ 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |

---

1. Binary of ShardID 3429        =         1101 0110 0101
2. Therefore (hashedValue >> 46) = 00 0000 1101 0110 0101
   &
3. 0xFFFF                        =    1111 1111 1111 1111
4. ShardId                       = 00 0000 1101 0110 0101

**Question Two:**

I understand need for 1. and 2. however I dont see why we need a bitwise operator & 0xFFFF since 4 & 2 are effectively the same.

**Question Three:**

I getting the following complier error: The literal 0xFFFFFFFFF of type int is out of range

```
public class BitExampleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      long pinId = 241294492511762325L;
      unHash(pinId);
    }

    private static long hash(int shardId, int typeId, int localId){
        return (shardId << 46) | (typeId << 36) | (localId << 0);
    }

    private static void unHash(long hashedValue){
               long shardID = (hashedValue >> 46) & 0xFFFF; 
               long typeID  = (hashedValue >> 36) & 0x3FF;
               long localID = (hashedValue >>  0) & 0xFFFFFFFFF;

               System.out.printf("shardID %s \n",shardID);
               System.out.printf("typeID %s \n",typeID);
               System.out.printf("localID %s \n",localID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Q3: use the literal long suffix: `0xFFFFFFFFFL`.

Comment: It's quite interesting that SO did not have an in-depth post on bit masks. +1 from me

Comment: There is no 'hashing values' here. All the input data is present in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They can have 2^16, range of 0-65536 shards?

Shard ID is 16 bits. So, 2<sup>16</sup> different Shard ID's are possible.

> Type ID of 2^10, range of 0-1024 types?

Type ID is 10 bits. So, 2<sup>10</sup> different Type ID's are possible.

> Local ID of 2^36, range of 0-68719476736 local id's?

Local ID is 36 bits. So, 2<sup>36</sup> different Local ID's are possible, i.e., pointers to 2<sup>36</sup> locations in the table are possible.

Now, referring to the [Pinterest post](https://engineering.pinterest.com/blog/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet), the Pin ID used to demonstrate is 241294492511762325.

At first glance, it is clear that this value won't fit in a Java `int` datatype. So, we switch over to `long`.

```
// 'L' added to tell the compiler it is a long, not an int
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(241294492511762325L)); 

// output (padded with 0's on the left)
0000 0011 0101 1001 0100 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0110 1011 1111 0111 1001 0101
```

Initially, ID of `241294492511762325` looks like this...

```
xx 00 0011 0101 1001 01 00 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0110 1011 1111 0111 1001 0101
XX [____SHARD(16)_____] [_TYPE(10)_] [________________LOCAL(36)_________________]
```

To get the Shard bits, right shifting ID by (10 + 36) 46 would work. This would get us. Please note that the bits to the left of XX can be either 0's or 1's, depending on **sign extension** of the 'final two bits', etc.

```
xx 00 0011 0101 1001 01
XX [____SHARD(16)_____]
```

Taking the bit-wise AND of this with 0xffff

```
           'our 2 golden bits'
                   ▼▼
  xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx 0000 1101 0110 0101
& 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 0110 0101
```

Regardless of what the leading bits were set to, now they are all 0's. I think that should make it clear to you, the reason behind the bitwise AND with 0xffff. If they are left-padded with 0's, great. If they aren't the AND takes care of it. :)

When you initialize a literal like 0xFFFFFFFFF, if there is no suffix and the variable is an integral type(int, long, etc), the value is assumed to be an `int`. And, an `int` can hold 32 bits, not 36 bits (9 x `0xF` = 9 x `'1111'`) like you are trying. So, you have to use a `long` that has a capacity of 64 bits. Appending 'L' or 'l' to the end of the value, like 0xFFFFFFFFFL, should take care of the compiler error. [[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)]

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, your ranges are correct, except that the maximum is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1.
2. Those final 2 bits ("worth their weight in gold") may cause havoc with the `shardId` value if ignored.  This bit-and ensures that they are masked out.  This also helps if you decide to implement those 2 bits in the future.
3. The type `int` in Java is limited to 32 bits.  Because each hex digit represents 4 bits, you can have a maximum of 8 hex digits in an `int` literal, but you have 9 `F`s.  You need a `long` literal, by appending `L`.

```
long localID = (hashedValue >>  0) & 0xFFFFFFFFFL;
```

Because your `localID` is 36 bits, an `int` is insufficient to hold all possible values, for the same reason as above.  Your `hash` method should take `localId` as a `long`.  You may need to cast your values as `long` before bit-shifting them to the left to avoid interpretation as an `int`, when the desired value is 64 bits (a `long`).